# Using SBApplication to open a URL in Safari?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to use SBApplication to tell a couple of browsers (Safari and Chrome) to open a given URL.  However, the apps just treat it like a file url.  Here's the pseudo/JSTalk code I'm using:

```
var safari = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.Safari"];
var url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://apple.com/"];
[safari open:url]; // results in opening "file:///http/::apple.com:"
```

Any hints?  Making a Safari.h file with sdp ( sdef /Applications/Safari.app | sdp -fh --basename "Safari" ) doesn't really help much to see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Just read that you wish to open an URL using multiple browsers. Thus, my answer isn't of help here:

I'd propose to ask NSWorkspace to open the URL:

```
// make an URL
NSURL *someUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://my.server.vom/" ];

if ([[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:someURL]) {
   NSLog(@"Fine. URL opened.");
} else {
   // shouldn't happen
}
```

Regarding your problem: Did you try to **pass a string** to Safari, not an NSURL?

Comment: Forcing the user to use a specific browser is bad indeed.